# Як перекласти «a new arrow one has in his quiver»?

Tags: переклад, фразеологізми

Дослівно: нова стріла, що з'явилася в чиємусь колчані. Але це вживають у переносному значенні (типу: нове вміння, новий засіб).

Наприклад, в статті [«This Man's Immune System Got a Cancer-killing Update»](http://nautil.us/blog/this-mans-immune-system-got-a-cancer_killing-update) («Людина, чия імунна система була покращена, щоб могти знищувати рак») є така фраза:

> Loren approached Ludwig about a new arrow that doctors at Penn had in their quiver.
>   (Лорен повідомила Людвіга про нову стрілу, яку лікарі [Пенну](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82) мали в своєму колчані.)

В російському перекладі на GeekTimes, наприклад, воно перекладене [так](//geektimes.ru/post/292143/):

> Лорен предложила Людвигу новый трюк, появившийся в списке у докторов института.
>   (Лорен запропонувала Людвігу новий трюк, що з'явився в переліку в докторів іституту.)

Але «трюк», на мою думку, є звуженням значення. «Нова стріла в колчані» (англійською) можна сказати про будь-який новий навик, нове вміння, нову здатність. «Трюк» же ж (англійське «trick»), щонайменше в програмуванні, має конотацію не якоїсь ґрунтовної навички, а дрібної, поверхневої чи напівхалтурної, яка не є надійною і не щоразу спрацює. Хоча в контексті вищезазначеної статті це частково так (еспериментальна недосліджена методика, результати якої на момент її застосування були непередбачувані, що спрацьовує не щоразу і іноді вбиває пацієнтів) — але в загальному випадку «new arrow in quiver», мені здається, такої конотації не має. Окрім того, «новий трюк у списку (переліку)» для мене виглядає якимсь недолугим.

Чи є якийсь український вислів, що добре відповідає виразу «new arrow in quiver»?

P. S.: [додаткова інформація про англійський вираз](//www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-the-expression-one-more-arrow-in-the-quiver).

Comment: Якби я перекладала, то відштовхувалась би не від *arrow*, а від *quiver*, як головного слова. І якби це був нейтральний контекст (на противагу літературному тексту, для якого, певно, є якийсь український відповідний фразеологізм, треба лиш згадати), то *in one's quiver* може бути *мати в запасі*, *мати в арсеналі*, а *arrow* - залежно від змісту тексту, наприклад: *ідея*, *думка*, *навичка*, *вміння* тощо. Втім, треба ще подумати.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, так, «мати в запасі» — цікавий варіант.

Comment: У певних стилях (не в запитуваному контексті) може бути доречним *у засіках*. [Засік](http://sum.in.ua/s/zasik): * Образно. Зрідка пролітає сніжок, тихий, пухнастий, — останні запаси вимітає із небесних своїх засіків зима (Олесь Гончар, II, 1959, 181);

Comment: Козир у рукаві, звісно, не те, але хоч трохи близько?

Comment: А взагалі quiver називається сагайдак, ні?

Comment: @ata_zh, СУМ містить обидва слова: і [колчан](http://sum.in.ua/s/kolchan), і [сагайдак](http://sum.in.ua/s/saghajdak)

Answer (score 3):

Ну, перш за все, гадаю, що переклад буде залежати від контексту:

> If you are having a job interview, improving your communication skills
>   **can be another arrow in your quiver** ([джерело](https://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/random-idiom.php?c=651)).

Гадаю тут можна перекласти як:

> Якщо ви збираєтеся на співбесіду, вдосконалення ваших навичків
>   спілкування **може виявитися тим, що стане вам у нагоді**.

А взагалі глянемо на визначення цієї ідіоми: "Ця ідіома використовується, щоб позначити одну із багатьох стратегій чи навичків, які можна використати для досягнення цілі".

> I've got a job interview next week, but I'm still handing out my
>   résumé so that **I'll have another arrow in the quiver**.
>
> У мене співбесіда аж наступного тижня, але я  ще досі відправляю свої
>   резюме, щоб мати **план Б** про всяк випадок.
>
> With all this varied job experience under my belt, I have more than
>   **one arrow in the quiver** if this particular career path isn't to my
>   liking.
>
> Із таким різноманітним досвідом у себе за плечима, у мене є **більше ніж
>   один запасний варіант**, якщо мені не підійде ця робота.

Щодо речення, яке ви навели у запитанні, гадаю, що тут ця ідіома може означати не лише трюк, але й, якщо у тексті йдеться, що ці доктори винайшли якусь нову технологію, то можна перекласти як:

> Лорен запропонувала Людвігу нову технологію, яку
>   професора інституту могли **використати як запасний варіант**.

Comment: виправте, будь ласка, на "навичок" або "навиків". якщо вам не складно, докладіть зусиль до редагування своєї відповіді. ставлю +, але очікую на відредагований текст. перш за все, "навичків", "вазгалі", "вивитися". дякую.

Comment: А звідки визначання «ця ідіома використовується…»? Загалом згоден, що можна перекладати по різному, в залежності від контексту, і з багатьма прикладами згоден. Але запропоноване «як **запасний** варіант» до оригінального контексту не пасує — там мова про варіант, що може стати в нагоді, але зовсім не запасний.

Comment: Визначення взяте із першого джерела.

Comment: Дякую, а Ви могли б додати це до тексту (наприклад, «а взагалі глянемо на визначення цієї ідіоми» → «а взагалі глянемо на визначення цієї ідіоми (в тому ж джерелі)»)? І ще — я все ще незгоден, що «використати як запасний варіант» підходить до оригінального тексту. Тобто з усією Вашою відповіддю згоден, але з фіналом — ні. Тому, мабуть, не буду поки що приймати, бо з фінальним «висновком» незгоден (хоча з рештою відповіді згоден).